# How to find a point on the border of a rectangle

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems, rectangles, fixed-points

I was wondering if it's possible to calculate points: A, B, C and D in the image I made below? And if it's possible, how?

Given are coords of points A2, B2, C2, D2. The distance between 'a1' - 'w', 'c' - 'v', 'b1' - 'b' and 'g' - 'p' is 7.071067811865475, in other words $5\sqrt 2$.

[image: obliquely oriented nested rectangles]

Comment: What other information do you have?

Comment: That's it. I have the x and y of the points A2, B2, C2, D2 and the distance between the lines.

Comment: $7.071067811865475 - 5\sqrt2$ is (approximately) zero. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Can you tell me more what the 'distance between the lines' is? I assume that it's shortest distance.

Comment: i meant that 7.07106781186547 in other words is  5sqrt(2). Not minus, sorry.

Comment: If it's shortest distance, then you have enough information. There will be exactly two points on the trapezoid with line a1 as its base and height |a1 - w|, with base angles $\pi/4$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I edited your post to make it easier on Readers.  Feel free to rollback my edit if I unintentionally changed your meaning.  [Mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) can be used here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At each corner, you can draw a little 45-45-90 isosceles triangle. The sides of that triangle are each $5\sqrt2$, so the hypotenuse is $10$. The hypotenuse is parallel to a coordinate axis, so the inner vertices you want are 10 units away from the outer ones in just one coordinate.